# AOP declare parents not working correctly in multiple inheritance

Tags: aop, aspectj, serializable, declare, parents

I have 2 classes: A,B. And A extends from B.
In my aspect I'm trying to declare parents for A and B to implements Serializable.

But for some reason, only B implements Serializable and A doesn't.
(See the orange arrow that is only on B)

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4UpWR.png)

If I switch the order between those lines, now A implements Serializable, and B doesn't.
(See the orange arrow that is only on B)

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VInwf.png)

Why this is happening?
How can I make both of them implements Serializable?

I'm working on Eclipse Luna 4.4.2 with AspectJ 1.8.7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `A extends B`, `A` inherits all implemented interfaces of it's superclass `B`. The declaration `declare parents: A implements Serializable;` hence does nothing, since `A` already implements `Serializable` through `B`.